# Geany and other IDE not writing to file

Tags: python, debugging, geany, pygal

I'm using Geany as my editor and when I first started using it, writing to files worked fine but somehow it randomly stopped working. The code executes without any errors but the file isn't created / is empty if already created and I've no idea why.
Simple code as below doesn't work:

```
filename = 'dogs'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('tester')

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

The output I get from the 'read' method looks correct on the console output (it just prints 'tester'), but no file is created / edited in my directory.

Geany also has a weirdly complex debugger (if anyone has any helpful guides on how to use it please let me know) so I can't debug properly. I've tried all that I know including using an absolute file path, running in admin mode. The issue is also present when I try to use Pygal to render_to_file(), which is the project I'm working on so right now I can't go any further because anything that requires writing doesn't work. FYI it reads fine.... It's like Geany doesn't have admin rights or something?

**EDIT**: I've run this code on a python shell (without a .py file) and it worked fine, creating the file as desired. I then ran it using CMD with the .py file and it didn't work. Also ran using Pycharm, it doesn't work when I run it normal but it works when I run it in debug mode? It doesn't seem to be a Geany specific issue, but I am so confused!

Comment: Can you try using an absolute file path rather than just a filename? e.g. point to a specific directory somewhere - such as /home/me/dogs.txt or c:/dogs.txt if on Windows.

Comment: Hi mate I did point out in the post that I've used an absolute file path (sorry if it was a TL:DR situation) but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution - the files were being created the whole time every time I ran my code, however my antivirus software **Comodo** contained them within a hidden folder in my drive which couldn't be found by a normal search.

I'm not sure if this a common problem with AV software or just Comodo, can't find anything on the net about it but there you go. I removed these files and the programs from its radar and it now works perfectly.

Although one mystery is how the python shell bypassed that problem. That threw me off thinking it was AV.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code works in the shell I strongly suspect the file is being created somewhere but you are looking in the wrong place.

I know you mentioned absolute paths but I just want to reiterate that you are not currently using an absolute path. An absolute path must start with a '/' (linux/mac) or something like: 'C:/' (windows).

Here are 2 things to try:

1) 
Change the name 'dogs' to something really obscure and then do a global search on your whole hard disk for that name. You'll probably find it.

2) Get python to tell you where the file is like this:

```
import os
filename = 'dogs'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('tester')
print(os.path.realpath(f.name))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't post the absolute file path here but I've definitely tried it. Looked something like this: 
    filename = 'C:/Users/Chiedozie/Documents/Coding 
    Resources/Python/python_work/File And Exceptions/dogs.txt' 
It didn't work either. Code ran without any errors. I've also tried the renaming the file and doing a global search, definitely didn't work.

I've just tried using the os method. Again, I get the output  of a filepath name on the console from the
    print(os.path.realpath(f.name)) 
function, but the file doesn't exist in the actual folder itself.

Comment: Right ok so I've found the files!!! (About a million of them from all my tests) I did a HD search like you suggested, went a bit deeper. They were created in some random **HIDDEN** folder which wasn't even specified in the absolute file path I wrote! So how on earth did they end up somewhere else even with an absolute path specified?? Because I can't even access them right now without a search.